# Launching a different ios app, within an app

Tags: ios

I'm writing a basic application using xcode 5.1. One of the features I'm interested in trying to do is to launch another app or move to other part of iphone, INSIDE the app already running.

Eg. I have an app with 3 menu options, 1 and 2 do certain tasks as part of this parent app, menu option 3 launches another app that's installed on the phone. I'm not sure if this is possible?

Comment: Wait till iOS8 buddy :P

Answer (score 1):

No you can not do that. Besides the documented URL handlers, there's no way to communicate with/launch another app.

This is part of the sandbox principle of apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html

What you can do is launch another app by using custom URL-Schemes

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Comment: Actually I wanna go to setting->wifi within my app,Please so tell me more about URL Handler for this